# Django facebook, twitter and google + authentication

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I need to get facebook, google+ and twitter authentication for my django app. What module should I use? I am using Django 1.8 and I've checked a couple of them but which one is the best? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suggest you to use django-oneall: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-oneall/1.0.2

Comment: Check out http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html Very extensive

Answer (score 0):

This is an approximation using the Django rest framework https://github.com/PhilipGarnero/django-rest-framework-social-oauth2. You should be familiarized with OAuth2 protocol (basically you use someone else's security to authenticate an user in you app). Also there is this library https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib, look at the documentation, it's pretty well explained and has examples with Tumblr, Facebook,etc. The lastone works with Python in general, no Django needed (just in case).

Answer (score 0):

Go for python-social-auth. It is good and well documented. You can start from [here](http://rahmonov.github.io/posts/introduction-to-python-social-auth/) for introduction.